# How to pass Stripe token from Android to ParseServer?

Tags: android, stripe-payments, parse-server

Welcome all!

I am currently working to pass a token generated by Stripes API from an Android app to a ParseServer. Below is my code, please be advised that I commented out previous failed attempts to let you know what I have tried and to also spark your imagination. Please note that with trial and error the issue presents to be with saving the data to the server. I have double checked that the class User has write permissions and it has an Object attribute titled token.

```
//  Test the data.
if (userCard.validateCard()) {
    Stripe stripe = new Stripe(CardActivity.this, "correct data is here I removed it, for StackOverflow");
    stripe.createToken(
        userCard,
        new TokenCallback() {
            public void onSuccess(final Token token) {
                // Send token to your server
                //  Query the users, and get the username.
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                String objectId = user.getObjectId();
                //  Query the current user.
                //query.whereEqualTo("objectId", username);
                ParseObject object;
                try {
                    object = query.get(objectId);
                    object.put("token", token);
                    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //  Attempt to update... Currently not working.
                /*query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null && objects != null) {
                            for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                                object.put("token", token);
                                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                       Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });*/
            }
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                // Show error message
                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this,
                    error.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                 ).show();
            }
        }
    );
} else {
    Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1) Parse allows you to add/overwrite information to objects from their "shell".  This is a ParseObject instance, set to a specified class, assigned an objectId, and then whatever values you want to add/change, and then saved.  Any field you did not assign a value to will be ignored, so say you only set field3, field2 and field1 will not be overwritten to nothing.

2) `ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` already returns a user object.  You don't even need to create a shell from the id, this is a fully functioning parse object.  You can then set the value you want and save it!

3) Queries and fetches (and cloud function calls) are asynchronous. This means that the code executes over time on a background thread, and your main thread will go on. So, things that require the results of these methods need to be called within the completion handler.  You're doing `object = query.get(objectId)`, but query.get() takes a bit to run so you're probably running through the rest of the code block before object has a proper value.

4) To my knowledge (not an Android developer, but I've used the JS and iOS SDKs) the Parse SDKs have a specific query for the User class that is a bit easier and safer to use than creating a ParseQuery set to the "User" class. Should be something like `ParseUser.query()`

So, not being an Android developer, I think what you want is more like this:

```
//  Test the data.
if (userCard.validateCard()) {
    Stripe stripe = new Stripe(CardActivity.this, "correct data is here I removed it, for StackOverflow");
    stripe.createToken(
        userCard,
        new TokenCallback() {
            public void onSuccess(final Token token) {
                // Send token to your server
                //  Query the users, and get the username.
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                try {
                    user.put("token", token);
                    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                // Show error message
                Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this,
                    error.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                 ).show();
            }
        }
    );
} else {
    Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use your code, which crashed my app. However, this did help me. I then attempted to pass a String value into a test field. It worked. I now know my issue is with the ParseServer accepting the token. I'll continue to work it. I'm looking at their documentation now. So thank you.

Comment: Sorry, as I said I'm not an Android devloper so nothing jumps out at me, except I left the Query declaration in there that now goes unused.  Do you know where it crashed? I might be able to get that, too.  You may have done something that set the token field on prase-server to a different type, so it doesn't like the String. Double check your table in the dashbaord.